# How to optimize huge query with repeated subqueries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have the following huge query that contains repeated subqueries , It looks really inefficient to me. How can i optimize it ?

```
SELECT T2.date1, T2.date2, T2.period, T1.market, T1.ticker, 0 AS scenario
FROM
(SELECT  DISTINCT
        Q.market AS market,
        Q.ticker AS ticker

FROM portfolio.scenario S RIGHT JOIN portfolio.quote Q
ON    S.series =  (SELECT S.series
                  FROM scenario S
                  WHERE S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
                        S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
                        S.period = 'QUARTER'
                  ORDER BY S.date2
                  LIMIT 1) AND
      Q.market = S.market AND 
      Q.ticker = S.ticker

WHERE  Q.date = '2010-07-01' AND
       S.date1 IS NULL) AS T1

JOIN 

(SELECT DISTINCT S.date1, S.date2, S.period
FROM scenario S
WHERE S.series = (SELECT S.series
                  FROM scenario S
                  WHERE S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
                        S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
                        S.period = 'QUARTER'
                  ORDER BY S.date2
                  LIMIT 1) AND
      S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
      S.date2 <= '2010-07-01') AS T2

UNION

SELECT  S.date1 AS date1, 
        S.date2 AS date2,
        S.period AS period,
        Q.market AS market,
        Q.ticker AS ticker,
        Q.close * EXP(S.ratio) AS scenario

FROM portfolio.scenario S , portfolio.quote Q

WHERE  S.series = (SELECT S.series
                  FROM scenario S
                  WHERE S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
                        S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
                        S.period = 'QUARTER'
                  ORDER BY S.date2
                  LIMIT 1) AND
      S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
      S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
      Q.date = '2010-07-01' AND
      Q.market = S.market AND 
      Q.ticker = S.ticker

UNION

SELECT T2.date1, T2.date2, T2.period, T1.market, T1.ticker, 0 AS scenario
FROM
(SELECT  DISTINCT
        Q.market AS market,
        Q.ticker AS ticker

        FROM portfolio.scenario S , portfolio.quote Q
        WHERE  Q.date = '2010-07-01' AND
              Q.market = S.market AND 
              Q.ticker = S.ticker AND
              S.series = (SELECT S.series
                  FROM scenario S
                  WHERE S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
                        S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
                        S.period = 'QUARTER'
                  ORDER BY S.date2
                  LIMIT 1) AND
              S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
              S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' ) AS T1

JOIN 

(SELECT DISTINCT S.date1, S.date2, S.period
FROM scenario S
WHERE S.series = (SELECT S.series
                  FROM scenario S
                  WHERE S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
                        S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
                        S.period = 'QUARTER'
                  ORDER BY S.date2
                  LIMIT 1) AND
      S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
      S.date2 <= '2010-07-01') AS T2


WHERE (T2.date1, T2.date2, T2.period, T1.market, T1.ticker)
        NOT IN (SELECT  S.date1 AS date1, 
                S.date2 AS date2,
                S.period AS period,
                Q.market AS market,
                Q.ticker AS ticker

        FROM portfolio.scenario S , portfolio.quote Q
        WHERE  Q.date = '2010-07-01' AND
              Q.market = S.market AND 
              Q.ticker = S.ticker AND
              S.series = (SELECT S.series
                  FROM scenario S
                  WHERE S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
                        S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
                        S.period = 'QUARTER'
                  ORDER BY S.date2
                  LIMIT 1) AND
              S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
              S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' )


ORDER BY 
date1,date2,period,market,ticker
```

After @[Bruce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99003/bruce-alderson) 's comment and some logic to reduce a subquery my query now is:

```
(SELECT S.date1, 
        S.date2,
        S.period,
        Q.market,
        Q.ticker,
        Q.close * EXP(S.ratio) AS scenario

FROM portfolio.scenario S , portfolio.quote Q

WHERE  
      S.date1 >= (@date1 := '2009-09-01') AND
      S.date2 <= (@date2 := '2010-07-01') AND
      Q.date = (@qdate := '2010-07-01') AND
      S.series = 
      (@series := 
                  (SELECT S.series
                  FROM scenario S
                  WHERE S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
                        S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
                        S.period = 'QUARTER'
                  ORDER BY S.date2
                  LIMIT 1)) AND
      Q.market = S.market AND 
      Q.ticker = S.ticker)

UNION

(SELECT T2.date1, T2.date2, T2.period, T1.market, T1.ticker, 0 AS scenario
FROM
(SELECT Q.market, Q.ticker
 FROM quote Q
 WHERE Q.date = @qdate) AS T1

JOIN 

(SELECT DISTINCT S.date1, S.date2, S.period
FROM scenario S
WHERE S.series = @series AND
      S.date1 >= @date1 AND
      S.date2 <= @date2) AS T2

WHERE (T2.date1, T2.date2, T2.period, T1.market, T1.ticker)
        NOT IN 

        (SELECT  S.date1,
                 S.date2,
                 S.period,
                 Q.market,
                 Q.ticker
        FROM portfolio.scenario S , portfolio.quote Q
        WHERE  Q.date = @qdate AND
               Q.market = S.market AND 
               Q.ticker = S.ticker AND
               S.series = @series AND
               S.date1 >= @date1 AND
               S.date2 <= @date2 ))
```

However, If i changed

```
  (@series := 
              (SELECT S.series
              FROM scenario S
              WHERE S.date1 >= '2009-09-01' AND
                    S.date2 <= '2010-07-01' AND
                    S.period = 'QUARTER'
              ORDER BY S.date2
              LIMIT 1))
```

to be

```
  (@series := 
              (SELECT S.series
              FROM scenario S
              WHERE S.date1 >= @date1 AND
                    S.date2 <= @date2 AND
                    S.period = 'QUARTER'
              ORDER BY S.date2
              LIMIT 1))
```

It takes too much time to process it (i have executed the query 10 mins ago and still did not get the result) while the query normally returns in 5 seconds.

Also when i reset the variables , execute the result is not correct (probably use the variable's value from the previous execution). How can i change that without adding SET statements (I would like it to be a single query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use MySQL variables:

```
SELECT
    @x := ColumnName,
    @y := ColumnName2 + @z,
    @z := (SELECT * FROM SubTable WHERE x = @x),
    (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE X = @z),
    (SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE X = @z)
FROM Table
WHERE
    v = @v
```

- You can assign subselect and column values to SQL variables
- You can refer to these variables anywhere in the statement
- The variables contain their value from previous rows (if set)
- You can reuse subselects and other values in this way

Comment: Thank you for the great advice , But in my query using such a line as @z := (SELECT * FROM SubTable WHERE x = @x) greatly increase the time to get the result set. I have re-edited the question to include the new query based on your comment and some logic to reduce a subquery

Comment: The savings there comes from using that variable in a number of columns (my example didn't show that so I updated it). I applied this recently to a piece of summary SQL that otherwise would have repeated windowed average calculations (subselect + grouping functions) for multiple columns.

Comment: Thanx dude for the feedback , Yes i used the concept with the @series variable. And i think in your example @z := (SELECT * FROM SubTable WHERE x = @x) , SubTable has only one column as @z won't be able to hold values from multiple columns.

Comment: SETs of results are probably better handled using temporary tables (or views?), depending on complexity of determining the set.